# Modelling Lookup Values in Domain

Tags: domain-driven-design, lookup, domain-model

In domain driven design, I have the following situation.

I have a Vehicle model. The vehicle can be of type HatchbackCar, SedanCar, Truck etc.

The VehicleType is stored in a database lookup table.

Question is:

How do I model the Domain?

Do I Model it like the following:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int VehicleId{Get;Set;}
    **public int VehicleTypeId { get; set; }**
    public string MakeCode { get; set; }
    public string ModelCode { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int PowerToWeight { get { return Power/Weight*100; } }     

}
```

OR

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int VehicleId{Get;Set;}
    **public VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; }**
    public string MakeCode { get; set; }
    public string ModelCode { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int PowerToWeight { get { return Power/Weight*100; } }     

}
```

AND

```
public class VehicleType
{
    public int VehicleTypeId{Get;Set;}
    public string Description{Get;Set;}   

}
```

If I use the 2nd way, at what stage do I populate the VehicleType model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
If I use the 2nd way, at what stage do I populate the VehicleType model.
```

**For both ways `VehicleType` should be set when you create a new instance of 'Vehicle'**, either `VehicleTypeId` or `VehicleType`.

1. If `Vehicle` refers to `VehicleTypeId` then you set specified identifier.
2. If `Vehicle` refers to `VehicleType` then you set an instance of `VehicleType`. First it is needed to load the instance of `VehicleType` with specified identifier

Usually I use the second approach since it describes domain model in terms of entities and their relations.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use an enum for `VehicleType` instead of using the id?
Your model can then contain the enum, which can be mapped to the database id afterwards.
I assume you need the descriptions for showing them in a dropdown or something like that?
This makes the `VehicleType` class a good candidate for a separate read model I guess.